# how can I print only capitalized names in this list and store the lowercase names in another list?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, while-loop, capitalization

```
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]
i = 0
while i < len(friends):
    print(friends[i])
    i += 1
else:
    print("Done")
```

how to use if condition to print only capitalized names from this list?

Comment: `[x for x in friends if x[0].isupper()]`. There's also [`islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower)

Comment: Don't use a while loop, use `for friend in friends:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lower_names = []
for name in friends:
    if name[0].isUpper():
        print(name)
    else:
        lower_names.append(name)
```

This should check if the first letter is capitalized, and print it if so. Otherwise, it goes into the other list.

Answer (score 2):

```
for name in [x for x in friends if x[0].isupper()]:
    print(name)

other = [x for x in friends if not x[0].isupper()]
```